# Boolean instanceof Object is true?

Tags: java, instanceof, primitive-types

I've been learning Java in my spare time and have a quick question I can't seem to figure out.  This code returns true:

```
Boolean testBool = true;
Boolean test = testBool instanceof Object;
System.out.println(test);
```

However, I thought Boolean was a primitive type and when I try this same logic with any other primitive type I get a compiler error that says: 
unexpected type required: reference found: int

I'm sure there's just something small I'm missing.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

boolean is a primitive type; java.lang.Boolean is its wrapper class.

You'll notice that all the primitive types have companion wrapper classes (e.g., int and java.lang.Integer, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

`Boolean` with uppercased initial `B` **wraps** a `boolean` primitive.  As [the docs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) say:

> The Boolean class wraps a value of the
>   primitive type boolean in an object.
>   An object of type Boolean contains a
>   single field whose type is boolean.

[Autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) can implicitly move between such boxed types and the corresponding primitives.